# How to permanently delete a feed in Azure DevOps's Artifacts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to remove a project-scoped feed in Azure DevOps's Artifacts because I'd like to use that feed name for an organization-scoped feed (which allows package sharing across different projects).

When I click "Save" in the feed renaming UI I get this error:

> The feed name 'myorg.internal' will be available soon.

Inspection of the browser Network tab shows this request fails with HTTP 409: `PATCH https://myorf.feeds.visualstudio.com/_apis/Packaging/Feeds/ee54xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx49c10d83`.

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "A feed with name 'myorg.internal' exists in feed recycle bin.
      The name will be available soon after it is permanently deleted from the feed recycle bin.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi.FeedNotReleasedException,
      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "FeedNotReleasedException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

**Is there a way to expedite the permanent feed deletion?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Once deleted, the feed will enter a disabled state for 30 days, after
>   which it will be permanently deleted. In this state, packages cannot
>   be installed, published, or manipulated and storage will not be
>   reclaimed. You may restore the feed to its original state, or
>   permanently delete it in the **feed settings** to clean up storage. This
>   feed name may not be reused until **permanently deleted**.

Please go to Deleted feed's Feed Settings,then click **Permanently Delete Feed** button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugh! My question is based on the steps you've described. I did all that and it took me more than an hour of waiting to be able to create a new feed with the same name... My question was if there's a way to make this process of permanent deletion take less than an hour. (At the time of writing I didn't know it takes 1 hour and thought it make actually take 30 days, which I tried to avoid).

Comment: According to Permanently delete prompt:`The feed name may not be reused for up to 15 minutes`. My test result is that I can reuse the feed name in less than 15min

Comment: I'll take it as "there is no way to expedite the permanent deletion".